# SQL Query - Determine A Supporters Status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been tasked with cleaning up data of an organisations supporters. Whilst I am okay with some SQL query coding I have run into a problem with something a bit more complex (well for me!).

The task is to mark supporters as active or lapsed.

I can do this by looking at their start date and if under two years from that date we can mark as active and anything over as closed. sadly nothing is ever that easy and a supporter may climb up an additional level depending on the way they interact with the organisation.

What I need the query to do is look to see if they have an additional supporter code. For example they cannot be active on two levels and I need the query to look to see if they are at the next level and if so lapse the previous code regardless of whether they meet the rule explained above. They can rise up to 5 levels.

I hope this makes sense. The data looks something like this.

```
Member ID | Category | Start Date | End Date
123456    | LEG1     | 01/12/2012 |
654321    | LEG1     | 01/01/2009 |   
421124    | LEG1     | 01/05/2011 |   
421124    | LEG2     | 02/04/2011 | 31/12/2012
421124    | LEG3     | 02/04/2011 | 31/12/2012
421124    | LEG4     | 31/12/2012 |   
567888    | LEG2     | 14/03/2012 |   
567888    | LEG3     | 22/08/2012 |   
119119    | LEG2     | 01/01/2011 | 31/12/2012
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: You talk about supporter codes and levels, but where is that in your data? Also it would be helpful if you showed us what you have tried. And best would be if you showed the expected result...

Comment: Sorry - the category is supporter code in the example given followed by a number. LEG1 is the lowest level with LEG4 being the highest in the example. For obvious reasons I couldn't use the proper data! Sorry if my original post was confusing.

Comment: Suggest editing the question so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE([Member ID] INT, Category VARCHAR(100), [Start Date] DATE, [End Date] DATE)
INSERT @t 
SELECT a,b,CONVERT(DATE, c, 104) c, CONVERT(DATE, d, 104)
FROM (VALUES
(123456 ,'LEG1', '01/12/2012', NULL),
(654321 ,'LEG1', '01/01/2009', NULL),
(421124 ,'LEG1', '01/05/2011', NULL),
(421124 ,'LEG2', '02/04/2011', '31/12/2012'),
(421124 ,'LEG3', '02/04/2011', '31/12/2012'),
(421124 ,'LEG4', '31/12/2012', NULL),
(567888 ,'LEG2', '14/03/2012', NULL),
(567888 ,'LEG3', '22/08/2012', NULL),
(119119 ,'LEG2', '01/01/2011', '31/12/2012')
-- I added these rows to sample data to show how borderline cases are treated
(100000 ,'LEG1', '17/02/2011', NULL),
(100001 ,'LEG1', '18/02/2011', NULL),
(100002 ,'LEG1', '19/02/2011', NULL)
) tbl(a,b,c,d)

SELECT  *
        , CASE WHEN 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Member ID] ORDER BY Category DESC) > 1
            OR 
            [Start Date] < DATEADD(YEAR, -2, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
          THEN 'lapsed' 
          ELSE 'active' 
          END [Status]
FROM    @t
ORDER BY
        [Member ID]
```

It checks for both of your conditions, `ROW_NUMBER()` function makes sure that rows that are not highest achieved category cannot be marked as active and `DATETIME` comparison between `[Start Date]` and today's date minus 2 years takes care of your second condition. If any of these conditions is met, record won't be marked as active.

Comment: Thanks Ivan G - is there away of doing this without using the Member ID? The group of records I am looking at number 19.000 approx. In the meantime I will see if I can adapt your query. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't think there's a way of doing it without that column. Other approach would be to use `GROUP BY`, but that would also involve `Member ID`. 19000 records is very small amount of data for SQL Server, when you adapt query for your table and try it, tell me if it worked as expected and fast enough.

Comment: Hi Ivan - you put me on the right track in designing a query using parts of your logic.. Thanks again.